# Fortran, best use of DIMENSION when initializing array with PARAMETER attribute

Tags: fortran

In Fortran, are these two methods for initializing a parameter array identical?  If not, what is the meaning of `dimension(*)`?

`integer, parameter, dimension(2) :: x = [1,2]`

vs

`integer, parameter, dimension(*) :: x = [1,2]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The effect of both declarations is the same: a rank-1 named constant array of shape `[2]` with the obvious values.

Using `dimension(*)` makes the array *implied shape* rather than explicit shape: the named constant is of shape implied by the constant expression.

Which is better?  Well, implied shape is not supported by all compilers (being a Fortran 2008 feature), but it saves worrying about writing shape twice.

Comment: GCC >v7.1.1 and Intel ifort >2018 appear to support the implied shape.